# SlidingMenuSharp System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Android.Widget.Scroller'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, scrollview, objectdisposedexception

We have a Xamarin.Android 7 app.
We are getting the following exception which causes the app to crash.
It says something about Android.Widget.Scroller, but we are not using this component explicitly in our app anywhere. 
We are using ScrollView and GridView in xaml files though.

One solution which we came across was to move back to Xamarin.Android 6, but that is not a feasible solution due to app requirements.
One more solution we came across was to use ListViewCachingStrategy, but couldn't find how to do that in Xamarin.Android.

Please help us out here, this is huge roadblock in our task.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Android.Widget.Scroller'.
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf (Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self) [0x00029] in <5716a943049b49ca928a3a1c8d2386f4>:0 
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualBooleanMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00000] in <5716a943049b49ca928a3a1c8d2386f4>:0 
at Android.Widget.Scroller.get_IsFinished () [0x0000a] in <8804aaaf21bc4f45b576b50092b57059>:0 
at SlidingMenuSharp.CustomViewAbove.ComputeScroll () [0x00001] in <20b4998942db4089b3ed88297710fab6>:0 
at Android.Views.View.n_ComputeScroll (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <8804aaaf21bc4f45b576b50092b57059>:0 
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:0044ef4c-4a4e-4ecd-8301-8be4cc63baea (intptr,intptr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `new` GC Bridge vs. the default `tarjan`:

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=new
```

Create an text file within your `Xamarin.Android` project and set a build type of `AndroidEnvironment` on it and include the `MONO_GC_PARAMS` line from above.

Rebuild and test your project.

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/#GC_Bridge_Options

Comment: I have a similar problem. Log looks the same but the object is Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FastRenderers.ButtonRenderer. Your solution didn't fix it. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Dpedrinha If it is `FastRenderers`-based issue, report it to Xamarin as the FastRenderers are still a work in progress : http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ After that, disable the fast renderers till they publish a fix to test....

Comment: God I was so close... I will, but they will ask for a repro and I most probably won't be able to reproduce it.

Comment: @jatinkinra Glad to hear it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Update Xamarin.Forms to 2.4.0-pre1 and it should be fixed.