# GC_MINOR(Nursery full) Xamarin app crashes

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, garbage-collection

I am new to mobile development and I am trying to make an Xamarin Android app using MVVM framework but I am stuck and getting the following error. I keep getting `GC_Minor(Nursary full)` entry in my output window and and after a while the it freezes and crashes the application.

Can somebody point me into the right direction on how should I solve this problem? Thank You!!!

## Stack

```
09-20 00:27:30.681 I/art     (10052): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1775(108KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 18MB/30MB, paused 1.686ms total 49.312ms
09-20 00:27:30.681 D/Mono    (10052): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 17 objects 839 opaque 893 colors 17 colors-bridged 17 colors-visible 17 xref 1 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.15ms tarjan 1.27ms scc-setup 0.13ms gather-xref 0.01ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.08ms
09-20 00:27:30.681 D/Mono    (10052): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 51.29ms
09-20 00:27:30.681 D/Mono    (10052): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 9.80ms, stw 11.54ms promoted 106K major size: 7600K in use: 6910K los size: 2048K in use: 956K
09-20 00:27:32.626 D/Mono    (10052): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 0 objects 0 opaque 0 colors 0 colors-bridged 0 colors-visible 17 xref 1 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.15ms tarjan 1.27ms scc-setup 0.13ms gather-xref 0.01ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.01ms
09-20 00:27:32.626 D/Mono    (10052): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 0.19ms
09-20 00:27:32.626 D/Mono    (10052): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 7.97ms, stw 10.12ms promoted 99K major size: 7712K in use: 7010K los size: 2048K in use: 956K
09-20 00:27:34.511 D/Mono    (10052): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 0 objects 0 opaque 0 colors 0 colors-bridged 0 colors-visible 17 xref 1 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.15ms tarjan 1.27ms scc-setup 0.13ms gather-xref 0.01ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.01ms
09-20 00:27:34.511 D/Mono    (10052): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 0.20ms
09-20 00:27:34.511 D/Mono    (10052): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 7.81ms, stw 9.15ms promoted 99K major size: 7808K in use: 7110K los size: 2048K in use: 956K
09-20 00:27:36.426 D/Mono    (10052): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 0 objects 0 opaque 0 colors 0 colors-bridged 0 colors-visible 17 xref 1 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.15ms tarjan 1.27ms scc-setup 0.13ms gather-xref 0.01ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.01ms
09-20 00:27:36.426 D/Mono    (10052): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 0.19ms
09-20 00:27:36.426 D/Mono    (10052): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 7.62ms, stw 8.94ms promoted 99K major size: 7920K in use: 7210K los size: 2048K in use: 956K
An unhandled exception occured.
```

## Update

```
09-19 07:26:01.242 E/mono    (14051): 
09-19 07:26:01.242 E/mono    (14051): Unhandled Exception:
09-19 07:26:01.242 E/mono    (14051): System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
09-19 07:26:01.242 E/mono    (14051): Parameter name: s
09-19 07:26:01.242 E/mono-rt (14051): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:     System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
09-19 07:26:01.242 E/mono-rt (14051): Parameter name: s
referenceTable GDEF length=814 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=47302 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GDEF length=808 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=49128 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GDEF length=808 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=49206 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GDEF length=814 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=47476 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
```

So after the GC_Minor warnings I get this unhandled exception. I updated xamarin a week ago to lastest version, does this have to do anything with the error I'm getting?

Comment: Without actually including the code and exception/stacktrace guessing is about all anyone can do: 1) You can try using the `new` vs the `tarjan` bridge : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45730311/4984832 2) capture and debug the exception 3) and follow the memory best practices guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/#lazy

Comment: @SushiHangover I have updated the question with the exception I am getting. Can you please look at it. Thanks!!

Comment: I can only see that your paramater s is null, show the relative code where you get this exception? Or are you saying that your app works fine before updating Xamarin?

Comment: Would it be possible to show us some code - that parameter "s" being null must come from somewhere.

Comment: @Ewald I didn't have any parameter "s" but it was still crashing. I solved the problem by modifying the Android options (Advanced) `HttpClient Implementation` and `SSL/TLS implementation`.

Comment: @NickKing Ah great, thank you for letting me know. I've not seen that one before, but I'll make a note of it.